# Shared components with ejected create-react-app projects

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, babel-loader

I have several projects that were created with `create-react-app` and have been ejected. Now, I have some components that are duplicated in each of the projects. Instead, I would like to have one shared component in a directory above the project directories.

The directory structure would be something like this:

```
 - shared_components
     - MySharedComponent.js
 - project1
 - project2
 - project3
```

I updated the `webpack.config.js` files in my projects to allow importing files outside the `src` directory by adding my `shared_components` directory to the `ModuleScopePlugin`:

```js
{
   resolve: {
      plugins: [
         new ModuleScopePlugin([paths.appSrc, paths.mySharedComponents], [paths.appPackageJson]),
      ],
   }
}
```

This successfully allows the files to be imported, but my `shared_components` directory doesn't seem to get compiled by the `babel-loader`.

I am getting the following error:

```
SyntaxError: /path/to/shared_components/MySharedComponent.js: Unexpected token <
```

This error occurs at the start of the JSX in my component, which is presumably caused by it never getting compiled to plain Javascript.

I tried updating the `babel-loader` config to include my shared directory, but it is not working:

```js
{
   test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
   include: [paths.appSrc, paths.mySharedComponents],
   loader: require.resolve("babel-loader"),
   // ...the rest of the config is just the defaults
}
```

How can I get my JSX component to successfully compile?

Comment: facing same issue.

Comment: @AmanVarshney I never solved this problem, but I did find a way around it. If you're using Yarn, you can use the `workspaces` feature to accomplish this: https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/workspaces/